# Collect all the files in a directory + test if one exists

Tags: vba

What is the cleanest solution in VBA for **collecting** the fullpath of all the files (strings) in a given directory **with the ability to test if one fullpath exists** in the collection?

My solution is to:

- get the collection using `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder`
- duplicate it to a new dictionary for having the "Exists" method

but I dislike it because it takes time to duplicate the list and because the dictionary requires to add a "item" (nothing) with every "key" (fullpath) :(

Comment: Trap the error on `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile` to check if file exists and just use the `files` collection.

Comment: FileSystemObject has a function `FileExits(filepath)`

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your issue. We need to see more code than just a line to be able to help you properly. One line of code does not show what you actually did and where your problem is in the code.